# Force location to have same pattern

Tags: nginx

I was wondering if it's possible to force location only accept when the route has pattern `[a-z]+:[a-z]+`. Example: `/events/prefix:sufix`

I've tried to reach it using:

```
    location ~ /events/([a-z]+:[a-z]+)$ {...}
```

Also, I would like to avoid stuff like `/events/prefix:sufix/more/more`. Is possible?

But it didn't work.

What's the proper way to set it?

Comment: Regular expression `location` statements are evaluated in order until a matching expression is found, so the placement of this statement within your `server` block is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).  Also, you might want to add a `^` to the beginning of the regular expression.

Comment: I've tried `location /events/(^[a-z]+)$` but it won't work. Only works with `location /events/(\w+)$`

Comment: @RichardSmith By the way, It only works using `\w` or `\d` or `\s` :(